# Maven + AspectJ/SpringAOP + Lombok + Surefire = test broken in a specific scenario

Tags: maven, aspectj, spring-aop, surefire

I have an interesting problem in a project where all of the technologies mentioned in the title are used. I've been able to track it down up to the diagnosis (the test classpath prepared by Surefire), but I don't understand whether it can be fixed and how. It's not a showstopper, indeed it's a minor issue for me, but I'd like to solve it anyway.

**First a rough description.**

The problem is related to executing tests in a specific module of the project, and only in a specific way.

Everything works (tests pass) when I run from the master pom level:

```
cd ${projHome}
mvn install
```

Everything works (tests pass) when I run:

```
cd ${projHome}/modules/CoreImplementation/
mvn test
```

That means that I can build and test with no problems, the same for my Jenkins, and NetBeans can run tests from the IDE when I need them.

But that module fails testing when I run from the master pom level:

```
cd ${projHome}
mvn test
```

with this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: it.tidalwave.northernwind.profiling.RequestProfilerAspect.aspectOf()Lit/tidalwave/northernwind/profiling/RequestProfilerAspect;
    at it.tidalwave.northernwind.frontend.ui.spi.DefaultSiteViewController.processRequest(DefaultSiteViewController.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.tidalwave.northernwind.frontend.ui.spi.DefaultSiteViewControllerTest.must_call_some_RequestProcessors_when_one_breaks(DefaultSiteViewControllerTest.java:161) ~[test-classes/:na]
```

Running `mvn test` as a second pass (after a `mvn install -DskipTests`) happens to be the way Drone.io and Travis do their job. While I could change their configuration, I'd like to stay with the standard configuration and fix the problem if possible.

**The diagnosis in short and my question.**

Now, the question in short (details are further below). I was able to track down the problem to different ways in which Surefire prepares the classpath to execute the tests.

When I run `mvn install` the classpath is:

```
${repo}/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.16/surefire-booter-2.16.jar  
${repo}/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.16/surefire-api-2.16.jar
${projHome}/modules/CoreImplementation/target/test-classes
${projHome}/modules/CoreImplementation/target/classes  
    ${projHome}/modules/Core/target/it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-1.1-ALPHA-37-SNAPSHOT.952b0c8bdc77.jar  
${repo}/it/tidalwave/thesefoolishthings/it-tidalwave-role/3.0-ALPHA-1/it-tidalwave-role-3.0-ALPHA-1.jar  
    ${projHome}/modules/Profiling/target/it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-profiling-1.1-ALPHA-37-SNAPSHOT.952b0c8bdc77.jar  
${repo}/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.0/commons-math3-3.0.jar  
…
```

When I run `mvn test` (from the project home) the classpath is:

```
${repo}/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.16/surefire-booter-2.16.jar
${repo}/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.16/surefire-api-2.16.jar  
${projHome}/modules/CoreImplementation/target/test-classes  
${projHome}/modules/CoreImplementation/target/classes  
    ${projHome}/modules/Core/target/unwoven-classes  
${repo}/it/tidalwave/thesefoolishthings/it-tidalwave-role/3.0-ALPHA-1/it-tidalwave-role-3.0-ALPHA-1.jar  
    ${projHome}/modules/Profiling/target/unwoven-classes
${repo}/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.0/commons-math3-3.0.jar  
…
```

The different portions are the indented ones. In the former case, SureFire uses the `classes` directory (forget for a moment that in my case they are named `unwoven-classes`) only for the module under test, and the installed jar files for every dependency. In the latter case, it seems to be using `classes` for all dependencies in the reactor.

The reason for which this difference in the classpaths gives me troubles is explained below in the "Gory details" section. In short, that `unwoven` means that they contain bytecode not augmented by AspectJ, hence the methods that can't be found at runtime.

I'm running with SureFire 2.16, but I've also tried the latest 2.19 with no changes. Being able to force SureFire to **always** use jar files for dependencies would fix my problems. If you have the answer, you can stop reading my post here.

**Gory details (just for curiosity).**

The faulty module artifactId is `it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-default` and it depends on aspects available in `it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-profiling` - that's where the offending `RequestProfilerAspect` is. The aspect library dependency is both in the regular dependencies of the faulty module and in the configuration of the aspectj plugin:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.tidalwave.northernwind</groupId>
  <artifactId>it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-profiling</artifactId>
</dependency>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <aspectLibraries combine.children="append">
          <dependency>
            <groupId>it.tidalwave.northernwind</groupId>
            <artifactId>it-tidalwave-northernwind-core-profiling</artifactId>
          </dependency>
        </aspectLibraries>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

AspectJ integration is by means of the following profile in a Super POM, which is activated in the build, whose relevant part is:

```
<profile>
  <id>it.tidalwave-aspectj-springaop-v1</id>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/unwoven-classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>target/unwoven-test-classes</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
```

The aspectj plugin is configured in the profile to statically weave binaries in the `unwoven-test-classes` directories. The reason for this approach is that it's the only feasible solution AFAIK to have both Lombok and AspectJ work together.

Now, back to the two classpaths described above: the fact that SureFire is using `unwoven-classes` means that it's pointing to bytecode that has not been augmented with AspectJ methods, hence the error.

References

The project is a FLOSS one and can be found at

https://bitbucket.org/tidalwave/northernwind-src

or

https://github.com/tidalwave-it/northernwind-src

A changeset where the problem can be reproduced is `f98e9a89ac70138c1b6bd0d4570a22d59ed71be6`. JDK 1.8.0 is required to build the project (even though it doesn't use Java 8 code yet).

The SuperPOM can be found here:

https://bitbucket.org/tidalwave/thesefoolishthings-superpom-src